# how to use path variable in californium CoAP server?

Tags: java, iot, coap

Similar with Restful syntax in Jersey or other framework, I could fetch the variable in the Restful uri path like that:

```
@Path("/users/{username}")
public class UserResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/xml")
    public String getUser(@PathParam("username") String userName) {
        ...
    }
}
```

but in californium, the syntax is different, I try these codes but it is not correct:

```
class usersextends CoapResource {

    public users() {
        super("users/{username}");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleGET(CoapExchange exchange) {

        exchange.respond("The username is "+ ???????);
    }
}
```

How could I use the same function as first piece of code did? Another thing is where I can find official document introduce the API? I just saw the source code and try to find the solution now.

Comment: If this is CoAP what does it have  to do with MQTT?

Comment: @hardillb I am implementing a data receiver on Android device (receive sensor data from lower level device). CoAP and MQTT could both satisfy the requirement, but I found it seems there is no existing MQTT broker project for android. I also want to ask solution from MQTT but forget to add it.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own MessageDeliverer and change findResource method:

```
public class MyMessageDeliverer implements MessageDeliverer {

  private final Resource root;

  public MyMessageDeliverer(Resource root) {
    this.root = root;
  }

  /* You can use  implementation of methods from ServerMessageDeliverer */
  @Override
  public void deliverRequest(Exchange exchange) {
  }

  @Override
  public void deliverResponse(Exchange exchange, Response response) {
  }

  /* method returns last known Resource instead of null*/
  private Resource findResource(List<String> list) {
    LinkedList<String> path = new LinkedList<String>(list);
    Resource current = root;
    Resource last = null;
    while (!path.isEmpty() && current != null) {
      last = current;
      String name = path.removeFirst();
      current = current.getChild(name);
    }
    if (current == null) {
      return last;
    }
    return current;
  }
}
```

Use your MessageDeliverer:

```
server = new CoapServer();
server.setMessageDeliverer(new MyMessageDeliverer(server.getRoot()));
```

Add your Resource to server:

```
server.add(new Users());
```

Request /users/{username} will be delivered to your Users resource. Fetch the variable from request URI:

```
public class Users extends CoapResource {

  public Users() {
    super("users");
  }

  public void handleGet(CoapExchange exchange) {
    List<String> uri = exchange.getRequestOptions().getUriPath();
    uri.remove("users");
    String username = uri.remove(0);

    //for query params:
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String p : exchange.getRequestOptions().getUriQuery()) {
      String[] parts = p.split("=");
      params.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }
    String param = params.get("param");

  }

}
```